# How can I call the parent of a MasterPage before the WebForm is processed?

Tags: c#, .net, events, webforms, viewstate

I have a Master page that inherit this:

```
public partial class PopupsDashboard : iMasterPageProtected
```

inside that `iMasterPageProtected` I make some operations.

I'd like to process these operations before the execution of the Web Form code-behind associated to this Master Page:

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/PopupsDashboard.master" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Aggrega.aspx.cs" Inherits="interne_appsocial_facebook_aggrega_Aggrega" %>
```

So I think I need to put the code of `Aggrega.aspx.cs` not in the Page_Load.

But, where?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The order of events in a page life cycle is this:

1. MasterPage Init
2. Page Init
3. Page Load
4. MasterPage Load

So, you should put your code in the Init event of your MasterPage

Here is the [complete ordered list of events](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dct97kc3.aspx).

> The general rule for how events are raised is that the initialization
>   events are raised from the innermost control to the outermost one, and
>   all other events are raised from the outermost control to the
>   innermost one. It is helpful to remember that the master page is
>   merged into the content page and treated as a control in the content
>   page.

Comment: Yes, Load on WF is loaded before the Load of the MasterPage. That's what I won't: I need that MasterPage is executed before.